# How to find blank cells in a range and then get reference to them

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-office-2010

Can anyone help me please,
Im using office 2010

I'm trying to find blank cells in a range (O2142:O2206) and the get reference to those cells.

And is there a way to only get reference to the row.

see image below:

I want it to look for the blank cells in column O (Date Job Delivered) because if there is cells that are blank, that means those jobs haven't been delivered and then I want it to get reference to column H (customer part number)

so that for the cells that are blank it gives me the part number in a list and that list would be a list of the parts that haven't been delivered.

Any help would be muchly appreciated, if there isn't a way to do it can you please show me a vba script that will work
Thank you

[Click to see image of of excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJkKL.png)

Comment: Is there something preventing you from filtering on blank dates and then copying the part numbers from the filtered results?

Comment: I want it all automated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column "parts that haven't been delivered" somewhere after column 'O', use the formula `=IF(O2="",H2,"")` in row 2 of the newly created column, then copy it and paste it all the way to the end of the column in your spreadsheet. Then you'll be able to filter your undelivered items using that column.

To somewhat automate it and not have to constantly copy the formula to newly created rows, use this formula `=IF(AND(H2<>"",O2=""),H2,"")` and copy it to the very end of the sheet. This will make it so as you enter new "Customer part numbers" in column H, it will trigger the "parts that haven't been delivered" column until a value has been entered into the "Date job delivered" in column O.

Comment: This works perfectly but when I insert a new row it doesn't bring down the formula how do  I get it to do this

Comment: Updated my answer for you. Hopefully that works. There are some other solutions, but from what I understand, this is how I would accomplish the task.

Comment: Hi Josh boss just told me in that it has to have the customer and the purchase order number how do I get reference to more than one column.  I need to get reference to column H, B and C

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat automated. You will need to adjust the rows that you want to search. I'm just searching for blanks in E1:E11.

Cell H2 formula (looking for blanks in column E):

```
    =IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTIF($E$1:$E$11,""),"",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",INDIRECT(TEXT(AGGREGATE(15,6,(10^5*ROW($E$1:$E$11)+COLUMN($E$1:$E$11))/($E$1:$E$11=""),ROWS($1:1)),"R0C00000"),0)),"$",""))
```

Cell I2 formula (return part number for those blanks):

```
    =OFFSET(INDIRECT(H2),0,-3)
```

Drag them down, and that's it.

[image]